# Sending event parameters in a jQuery trigger to an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm triggering click events from a parent window to an embedded iframe (of the same origin) and am having no trouble picking up the event, but I can't access custom parameters. Here's what I'm doing...

**Parent:**

```
var iframe_doc = window.child_frame.document;
var clickEvent = jQuery.Event("click");
clickEvent.fromParent = true;
$("p", iframe_doc).trigger(clickEvent);
```

**Child (iframe named child_frame):**

```
$(document).click(function(e){
  if(typeof e.fromParent === 'undefined' || e.fromParent != true) {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

When I do something like this within the context of just one page, it's not a problem and I can see the event. But between documents, the `fromParent` property is not set. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Just checking: are you 100% sure that the binding is made before the triggering?

Comment: Are you getting the event when consoling `$(iframe_doc).data('events');`?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Well, If it’s not there, it’s not going to be triggered either... Seems like it never gets transfered at all, regardless of what properties you put on the event object.

Comment: Nah, the even definitely gets triggered. Just, not with the properties on the event object.

Comment: That sounds very strange, to my knowledge all jQuery events are saved and accessible through the `.data('events')` method. It might exist in the iFrame `document`, but not in the iframe_doc reference.

Comment: That seems to be it, yes. Yet, the extra data I've passed with the event isn't there =(

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation, you can add properties by passing an object to the constructor:](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

> As of jQuery 1.6, you can also pass an object to jQuery.Event() and
>   its properties will be set on the newly created Event object.

That is, in your case:

```
var clickEvent = jQuery.Event("click", { fromParent: true });
```

Have you already tried it?